How to calculate the partial derivates in the origin $(0,0)$
Study the continuity, derivability and differentiability in the origin of the following function:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}&\quad\text{when}\:(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0&\quad\text{when}\:(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}
$$

The problem is to calculate the partial derivatives in the origin, $\partial_xf(0,0)=\partial_yf(0,0)=0$. The question is, if the function is zero in the Coordinate axes why are the partial derivatives also zero in the origin? Students in a university course asked me to develop the partial derivatives and the reason why they were zero. We had
\begin{align*}\partial_x f(x,y)&=\frac{y^2(x^2+y^2+|xy|)-xy^2(2x+\operatorname{sgn}(x)|y|)}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}
\\
&= \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}-\frac{xy^2(2x+\operatorname{sgn}(x)|y|)}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}
\end{align*}
How should I continue? Do I have to make a limit for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ of $\partial_x f$ to get $\partial_x f(0,0)$ i.e. $\lim_{\to(0,0)}\partial_x f (x,y)=\partial_x f(0,0)$? Shall I conjecture that the limit is null and make an upper bound?
\begin{align*}\left|\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}-\frac{xy^2(2x+\operatorname{sgn}(x)|y|)}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}-0\right)\right|&\\
=\left|\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}-\frac{2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}-\frac{x+\operatorname{sgn}(x)y^3}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}\right|&\end{align*}
The first addend is less than $1$ (if we see the fraction in the variable $y$ alone the ratio of the coefficients of $y^2$ is $1$).
For the second addend, the degree of the numerator is $4$ and if I developed the square of a trinomial I would have a piece containing the term $2x^2y^2$. Considering that at the numerator and denominator I would have $2x^2y^2$ the limit is greater than $1$. The last one should come to $0$. But I don't know how to do the third limit and continue. The same for $$\partial_y f(x,y)=\frac{2xy(x^2+y^2+|xy|)-xy^2(2y+\operatorname{sgn}(y)|x|)}{(x^2+y^2+|xy|)^2}$$ which has the same structure as $\partial_x f$.
PS: $\operatorname{sgn}=\operatorname{signum}$.

In general, partial derivatives at the origin have nothing to do with partial derivatives at nearby points.

@TedShifrin Thank you for your response. But in my question and steps how can I demonstrate that the partial derivates is 0?

Easy way to compute:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{f(y,0)-f(0,0)}{y}=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{0}{y}=0$$

Thank you very much. It is useful. But in my steps how can I to find the solution?

@Sebastiano I don't think that this is a right approach to get it since what you did was $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$, then you let $x_0,y_0\to 0$. But, it is not always true that the partial derivative is continous at the point $(0,0)$. Checking the definition is always correct.

Thank you very much again.

You are welcome.
